# Python/PyGame functions not working as hoped

Tags: python, pygame

I have this project to create a game with a main menu. I have created a very basic main menu at the moment just for prototype purposes. I have my main menu load up and then i want to hit "f" to play game, but it's not working as hoped. When i launch it the g It was fine before I added the functions, but i need these functions. Anybody got any ideas? Thanks.

```
import pygame, math, sys, random
pygame.init()

#Variables
darkYellow = 204,204,0
grey = 102, 102, 102
black = 0, 0, 0
white = 255, 255, 255
red = 255,0,0
marroon = 120, 0, 0
green = 0,255,0
blue = 0,0,255
darkBlue = 0,0,128

resolution = 650, 600
myFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 30)
myFont2 = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 15)
myFont3 = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 60)

redLeft = 150, 575
redRight = 280, 575
blackLeft = 370, 575
blackRight = 500, 575
radius = 20

window = pygame.display.set_mode(resolution)
window.fill(grey)
pygame.display.set_caption('Harrys Game')

def mainMenu():
    rectWidth = 150
    rectHeight = 40

    #Draw buttons
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (white),(250, 150, rectWidth, rectHeight),0)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (white),(250, 225, rectWidth, rectHeight),0)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (white),(250, 300, rectWidth, rectHeight),0)
    highlight = pygame.draw.rect(window, (darkYellow),(250, 150, rectWidth, rectHeight),0)
    pygame.display.update()

    playGameText = myFont.render("Play Game", 1, red)
    window.blit(playGameText, (260, 150))
    optionsText = myFont.render("Options", 1, red)
    window.blit(optionsText, (275, 225))
    exitText = myFont.render("Exit", 1, red)
    window.blit(exitText, (300, 300))
    pygame.display.update()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit(); sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_f:
                break
            game()

def game():
    while False:
        startBar = pygame.draw.lines(window, black, False, [(0,545.46),(541.7,545.46)], 5)
        bar2 = pygame.draw.lines(window, black, False, [(0,490.92),(541.7,490.92)], 5)
        bar3 = pygame.draw.lines(window, black, False, [(0,436.38),(541.7,436.38)], 5)
        bar4 = pygame.draw.lines(window, black, False, [(0,381.84),(541.7,381.84)], 5)
        bar5 = pygame.draw.lines(window, black, False, [(0,327.3),(541.7,327.3)], 5)
        bar6 = pygame.draw.lines(window, black, False, [(0,272.76),(541.7,272.76)], 5)
        bar7 = pygame.draw.lines(window, black, False, [(0,218.22),(541.7,218.22)], 5)
        bar8 = pygame.draw.lines(window, black, False, [(0,163.68),(541.7,163.68)], 5)
        bar9 = pygame.draw.lines(window, black, False, [(0,109.14),(541.7,109.14)], 5)
        bar10 = pygame.draw.lines(window, black, False, [(0,54.6),(541.7,54.6)], 5)

        #Draw side columns
        rightBar = pygame.draw.lines(window, black, False, [(541.7,600),(541.7,0)], 5)
        leftBar = pygame.draw.lines(window, black, False, [(108.3,600),(108.3,0)], 5)
        centreBar = pygame.draw.lines(window, black, False, [(325,0),(325,600)], 5)

        #Right column text
        label1 = myFont2.render("You rolled a:", 1, black)
        window.blit(label1, (545, 20))
        rollLabel = myFont2.render("Hit space", 1, black)
        window.blit(rollLabel, (545, 100))
        rollLabel2 = myFont2.render("to roll again", 1, black)
        window.blit(rollLabel2, (545, 117))


        #Display column numbers
        start1 = myFont.render("START", 1, black)
        window.blit(start1, (8, 545.46))
        side2 = myFont.render("2", 1, black)
        window.blit(side2, (54.15, 490.92))
        side3 = myFont.render("3", 1, black)
        window.blit(side3, (54.15, 436.38))
        side4 = myFont.render("4", 1, black)
        window.blit(side4, (54.15, 381.84))
        side5 = myFont.render("SAFE 5", 1, black)
        window.blit(side5, (8, 327.3))
        side6 = myFont.render("6", 1, black)
        window.blit(side6, (54.15, 272.76))
        side7 = myFont.render("7", 1, black)
        window.blit(side7, (54.15, 218.22))
        side8 = myFont.render("8", 1, black)
        window.blit(side8, (54.15, 163.68))
        side9 = myFont.render("9", 1, black)
        window.blit(side9, (54.15, 109.14))
        side10 = myFont.render("10", 1, black)
        window.blit(side10, (54.15, 54.6))
        finish11 = myFont.render("FINISH", 1, black)
        window.blit(finish11, (8, 0))
        pygame.display.update()

        redCountLeft = pygame.draw.circle(window, marroon, redLeft, radius)
        redCountRight = pygame.draw.circle(window, marroon, redRight, radius)
        blackCountLeft = pygame.draw.circle(window, black, blackLeft, radius)
        blackCountRight = pygame.draw.circle(window, black, blackRight, radius)

mainMenu()


pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: "it's not working as hoped" is a very poor problem description. Care to elaborate?

Comment: I meant that it should just launch and be fine. Thats what i hoped for :/

Comment: It doesn't "just launch and be fine"? Thanks for the information. Read this: http://sscce.org

Comment: I explained it; It should run a menu, the one i designed and then when i hit f it should launch the "game" function which included the game.

Comment: *And what happens instead?!* Error messages, nothing, odd output? What have you tried to do to fix it? Added some `print` lines to check variables? Tested each function separately in an interpreter?

Comment: Nothing, as i said in the description, it loads up but when i hit f nothing happens, i don't know it's the way i formatted my code, as i'm only in Secondary School, i'm new-sh to programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

`main_menu()` has a `while True:` loop with no `break`, `raise` or `return`, so would continue looping indefinitely if ever called.

`game()` contains a `while False:` "loop" that will never start.

This line makes no sense:

```
mainMenu() == False
```

and nor does:

```
game() == True
```

For some reason, you define functions (e.g. `def counters:`) then just call them straight away (e.g. `counters()`).

When you run your code, this happens:

1. All the definitions before `def main():` happen;
2. `main` is defined then immediately called;
3. `mainMenu` is defined;
4. `game` is defined then immediately called, but doesn't do anything (see above);
5. `counters` is defined then immediately called; and
6. You call `pygame.display.update()`.

*That's it*. `mainMenu` is never called (a good thing, as it would uselessly loop forever).

A pseudo code suggestion:

```
set up variables

set up window 

main menu:
    setup on screen text
    while True:
        get user input 
        if correct user input:
            break
    call game

game:
    while True:
        play game

call main menu
```

Comment: Thanks, ill get on to it. also do you know how i could call the game function from main menu? as Game is called after the main menu?

Comment: To call a function, just do `function()`. You should generally define *all* of your functions (`def function():`) *then* call the "entry point" (e.g `main`) at the end of the script.

Comment: I'm still confused i moved the calls to the end of the program and now the text just flickers and the program freezes.

Comment: I'd guess you're still only looping through the first half of `mainMenu`, just putting the buttons and text on the screen again and again and again and... Take ten minutes, sit down and draw out what should happen, in what order, where you need to loop, where you need to wait for input. *Then* write the code.

Comment: Yes, but i thought if i had that then when i hit "f" or what ever key i use for enter then it should turn the loop to false and then turn the game to true, so the main menu disappears?

Comment: I have changed my code now, and when i hit "f" nothing happens. Look in the full question and i updated the code.

Comment: You can't "turn the loop to False". *The code never leaves that loop*, never gets to the point where you can take input. Is that what e.g. `game() == False` was supposed to do? That's not how Python works

Comment: Yes it is. Have you seen the updated code? Do you know whats wrong with it now? It's just not doing anything when i hit "f" :/

Comment: Sorry it didnt chanfge at first, just updated again :)

Comment: I see you edited and added some Pseudo, at the main menu function, how would i call "game" if "game" is below the "mainMenu" function?

Comment: Better, but still `while False` which will *never work*! Remember that you define main menu, then define game, and *only then* actually call main menu, so game will exist by the time main menu actually tries to call it.

Comment: I got rid of While false and now the program shows both the menu and the game all together :/

Comment: Look at the indentation in my pseudo! Again, *draw out* what should happen, *then* write code that has the appropriate flow. Also, you'll need to blank the screen when `main menu` stops and `game` starts.

Comment: I don'#t think it's the indents. It's just instead of only loading the menu, it loads both the menu text and the game

Comment: I got it working, but now before i get a chance to hit "f" the window stops responding.

Comment: Your call to `game` is too far indented, it should happen *outside* the `while True` loop. I will not comment further here, this has gone on too long. Please follow my general advice, rather than "programming" by iterative Stack Overflow questions.